# tcl: How to break from script into tclsh / interpreter?

Tags: python, shell, tcl, interpreter

I am looking for a way to set a breakpoint in a script so that when the script is executed and hits this breakpoint, it'll activate tclsh so that I can manually inspect (and play with) code from thereon. A similar behaviour can be achieved in python via pdb.set_trace(). Is there a way to accomplish this in Tcl, too?

I have tried to set tcl_interactive, but this doesn't seem to alter the flow of the script at all, i.e. the script just progresses aftewards as usual.

```
set ::tcl_interactive 1
```

Comment: How did you launch the script?  Are you starting it from inside the interactive interpreter?

Comment: I am starting it from the command line, with shebang set to #!/usr/bin/tclsh.

Comment: Tcl has no such concept.  However, you can embed a function in your script that simulates the interactive interpreter.  https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Breakpoints+in+Tcl